# Python 2.7 cannot rename file under Window 7 64bit

Tags: python, file-rename

First of all, please be gentle - I am NOT a programmer - I am running a python script provided to me on a forum.  I've tried to get hold of the author, but no success.  The computer is running Windows 7, 64bit, and I am the administrator.

Background - this script deals with terrain files (.dsf) used by the flight simulator X-Plane 10 to create the ground mesh.  I need to edit the mesh elevations to smooth out and correctly contour the surface.  In X-Plane 10, a DSF file cannot directly be worked on.  It is decompiled with a tool provided by the X-Plane publishers.  When decompiled, a DSF produces a text file (which can be edited) and a image file which contains the actual elevation values for the mesh.  The image file produced is a .RAW file (not the same as a RAW from a camera...) and the naming convention is (DSF file name).elevation.raw

This script is designed to pull a matrix of elevation values (within bounds provided to the script at runtime) and either display them, or write them to a CSV file for editing.

I am able to run all functions of the script - except that when trying to run it to insert the new elevations, it reports back that it cannot rename (DSF file name).elevation.raw to (DSF file name).elevation.raw.BAK, and exits.  I include the code that (I think?) deals with the renaming functions.  I am running the script under Python2.7.6 (32bit) and in the directory where the file is located.  The error message I'm getting is on line 9 & 10:

```
def backupOrigRenNew(origFile):
   timeTuple = time.localtime()
   suffix = '_BAK%08d_%06d' % \
        (int(timeTuple[0]*1e4 + timeTuple[1]*1e2 + timeTuple[2]), \
         int(timeTuple[3]*1e4  + timeTuple[4]*1e2 + timeTuple[5]))
   try:
      os.rename(origFile, origFile+suffix)
   except:
      print 'Error: Cannot rename', origFile, 'with BAK<time> suffix.'
      print '       Aborting modification operation.'
      sys.exit(0)

   try: 
      os.rename(origFile+'.MOD', origFile)
   except:
      print 'Warning: Cannot remove temporary suffix:', origFile+'.MOD'
      print '         That is your modified file.'
```

If need be, I can post more of the script here, the author indicates in the script header that he welcomes modifications, etc - but it's not my code really.  I'm not sure if I've included enough to give you all the information you need to debug.

Many thanks in advance,

Edd

Edit 01 - February 01, 2014 in response to Igauananaut's request:

I've replaced the "sys.exit(0)" with "raise" as requested, this is the cmd shell output:

```
D:\terrain\+44-080>python rastertool3.py -C +44-080.txt.rastertool.csv
Error: Cannot rename +44-080.txt.elevation.raw with BAK<time> suffix.
       Aborting modification operation.
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "rastertool3.py", line 266, in <module>
    sel2rast()
  File "rastertool3.py", line 183, in sel2rast
    backupOrigRenNew(dsfTxtFile+'.elevation.raw')
  File "rastertool3.py", line 146, in backupOrigRenNew
    os.rename(origFile, origFile+suffix)
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by       another process
```

So it appears that the file is in use - I'm guessing by the actual rastertool3.py script?  Is there anyway of telling?

edd

Comment: Because the code does not tell is what caused the rename to fail there's not much that can be said.  Replace the "sys.exit(0)" with "raise" (make sure it has the same amount of indentation) and post the traceback that gets dumped when you run the code.  Then the actual error won't be obscured.

Comment: 1. Is the file located in your `Program Files` directory? If so, you need to run the python script as an administrator to make it work since `Program Files` is a system protected directory.

2. Is there any application currently using your file? For instance X-Plane? If so, the file might be locked and thus inaccessible. Try shutting down all programs that have any relation to the file before running the script.

Comment: Thank you all for your input - I have modified the original script as Iguananaut asked with "raise" replacing "sys.exit(0)"; Here is the output from the command shell:

Comment: I've modified the original question above with the output from Iguananaut's post.  To answer Immortal, no, it is not in the "Program Files" directory.

Comment: I've run Process Explorer - cmd.exe is the only process accessing that directory that I can see - I would guess running the script?